# Logical grouping in git over physical directories

Tags: git

I am doing couple of projects dependent on some common component. Say

Project A

- COMMON_LIB
- LIB_A
- APP_A

Project B

- COMMON_LIB
- LIB_B
- APP_B

Project B_PLUS

- COMMON_LIB
- LIB_B
- APP_B_PLUS

I have directory structure as ...

- common_resources
- makefiles
- doc
- src/common_lib
- src/lib_a
- src/app_a
- src/lib_b
- src/app_b
- src/app_b_plus

I want to checkin these in git. but i want something logical group(I don't know how) so that If a person want to checkout project A, he will get

- common_resources
- makefiles
- doc
- src/common_lib
- src/lib_a
- src/app_a

and if a person want to check out project B, he will get

- common_resources
- makefiles
- doc
- src/common_lib
- src/lib_b
- src/app_b

similarly if a person want to checkout project B+, he will get

- common_resources
- makefiles
- doc
- src/common_lib
- src/lib_b
- src/app_b_plus

how can I do this.

*if this is not possible, then how can I achieve same goal with some alternate way or tool*

**I am using GitLab**

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/git-project-dependencies